# The zeroes of $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 + 4x^2+ c$, for real $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> Let $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 + 4x^2+ c$, where $c$ belongs to real numbers. Then
>
> (A) $f(x)$ has infinitely many zeros in $(1, 2)$ for all $c$
>
> (B) $f(x)$ has exactly one zero in $(1, 2)$ if $-1 < c < 0$
>
> (C) $f(x)$ has double zeros in $(1, 2)$ if $-1 < c < 0$
>
> (D) whatever be the value of $c, f(x)$ has no zero in $(1, 2)$

My attempt: $f'(x)=0$ for terminal values of $x$. Therefore $x=0,1,2$

$f(0)=c,f(1)=1+c, f(2)=c$, therefore $f$ is maximum is at $x=1$. Not sure how to proceed further. Hints are appreciated.

Comment: An oddity of MathJax appears here. In LaTeX and in MathJax a hyphen in the code in math mode gets rendered as a minus sign, not as a hyphen, but an en-dash in math mode appears as an en-dash rather than as a minus sign, thus: $$ \begin{align} & \text{a hyphen in the code: } & a-b \\ & \text{(The above is rendered as a minus sign.)} \\ & \text{hyphen in what is rendered: } & a\text{-}b \\ & \text{an en-dash in the code: } & a–b \end{align} $$ Accordingly I changed the en-dashes in the code in this question to hyphens, so that you see  $x^4-4x^3$ rather than $x^4–4x^3. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use $f'(x)=4x(x-1)(x-2)$, clearly $f$ is srtictly decrasing on $(1,2)$,
now see option $(B)$ $f(1)=c+1>0, f(2)=c<0$ so by IVT it has at least one root in $(1,2)$, but since the funtion is strictly monotone, so this root is unique.

Answer (score 2):

For any $1<x<2$ we have: $$f(x)>c.$$
Also, for any $1<x<2$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$f(x)=(x(2-x))^2+c\leq\left(\frac{x+2-x}{2}\right)^4+x=1+c.$$
The equality does not occur.

Now, proof that $f$ is monotonic on $(1,2).$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$f(x)=(x^2-2x)^2+c$$

Now $x^2-2x=(x-1)^2-1\ge-1$